# phpUnit: Upgrade test cases from simpleTest to phpUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, automated-tests, simpletest

Is there any publicly available resource or migration of some form which can help in converting the existing test cases and test suite from simplTest to phpUnit framework?

As manually converting thousands of test case is not feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This script](https://gist.github.com/lox/4197196) should do most of the job.

You may also find useful information about migrating from simpleTest to PHPUnit [here](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/SimpleTest_conversion).

But you certainly will have to fix a few things by hand. Good luck!